# How to redirect to specific path in Rake Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to redirect to specific path in controllers using this rake routes path.
how to do it? thank you for the help.
[please click this image screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTtal.jpg)
Specific path is : "client GET /clients/:id(.:format) clients#show

```
     enrollment GET    /enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#show
            PATCH  /enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#update
            PUT    /enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#update
            DELETE /enrollments/:id(.:format)      enrollments#destroy
    clients GET    /clients(.:format)              clients#index
            POST   /clients(.:format)              clients#create
edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)     clients#edit
     client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)          clients#show
            PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)          clients#update
            PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)          clients#update
            DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)          clients#destroy
   register GET    /register(.:format)             clients#new
      login GET    /login(.:format)                logins#new
            POST   /login(.:format)                logins#create
     logout GET    /logout(.:format)               logins#destroy
 references POST   /references(.:format)           references#create
```

new_reference GET    /references/new(.:format)       references#new
      reference GET    /references/:id(.:format)       references#show
    preferences POST   /preferences(.:format)          preferences#create
 new_preference GET    /preferences/new(.:format)      preferences#new
     preference GET    /preferences/:id(.:format)      preferences#show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `redirect_to` `clients#show` then in controller simply write

```
redirect_to client_path(:id)
```

provided that you have to pass `client_id` in place of `id` in brackets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me a lot as newbie